# NPM - JavaScript Import/Concat/Compile ( like SCSS )

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm searching a npm tool to buil my JS files, something like SCSS where i have the main file with imports.
The main goal is to create a BAT file to use in PhpStorm file watcher to auto-compile my js files.

For example with this files :

```
app/
   _main.js
   _utilities.js
app.js
```

app.js, somethin like :

```
@import "app/_utilities.js";
@import "app/_main.js";
```

the final file should be the compilation of the 2 subfiles.

Hope i can have some help.
thanks!

Comment: Is webpack what you're looking for?

Comment: hi, i wanted a cli to use in a BAT file, so i dont think so (i dont really know webpack). I was loocking for something to call in CMD.

Comment: you can run webpack in batch though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search i finaly found the solution that I need :

bundle-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-js

Just like scss it lets you create a main js file with the includes of other javascript files.

Sadly unlike noda-sass it does not detect the parent main file and only compile this one when setup as watcher so I setup this workflow on the BAT file.

Answer (score 0):

**What need is a *module bundler*.**

There are many bundlers for JavaScript but [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) are among the most popular choices.

---

The following description is from Webpack's [official documentations](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/):

> ***Webpack*** is a *module bundler* for modern JavaScript applications.
>   When webpack processes your application, it recursively builds a dependency graph that includes every module your application needs, then packages all of those modules into a small number of bundles - often only one -

The following image makes it easier to understand what it does:

[image: webpack dependency tree]

Comment: hi, ty for the reply but i dont understand how any of this bundlers work :/ after a quick read on the documentation I dont see how i can require/include de JS files :S